# How to verify SSL certificates without root certificate in Python?

Tags: python, ssl, https, openssl, pyopenssl

I want to verify SSL certificate of a server which has an intermediate certificate between the root CA certificate and server certificate.

If have tried 'requests' and also 'httplib' package to verify the certificate and both succeeds if I provide the path(or update 'REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE' environment variable in case of 'requests') to the root certificate.

However if I provide path to only the server certificate or the intermediate certificate, verification fails. I was wondering is there any way for 'requests' or 'httplib' or any other package in Python to successfully verify SSL certificate with only server or intermediate CA certificate without trying to trace back to root CA certificate?

If it is tricky with Python, does openssl or similar linux tools allow the same?

Answer (score 2):

> How to verify SSL certificates without root certificate in Python?

You can use one of the Subordinate CA's rather than the Root CA to verify the certificate chain. This is called path building, and there's a [RFC that covers the technique](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4158).

You can also use the end-entity server certificate directly. Just root your trust in it rather than the Root CA or Subordinate CAs.

If you can't use the Root CA or Subordinate CAs, then you have to move on to another scheme.

---

This does not answer your question directly... One thing you can do is [pin the host's public key](https://www.google.com/search?q=public+key+pinning), and forgo the whole PKI or PKIX machinery.

The [key distribution problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+the+key+distribution+problem) still applies, and there's no way to side-step it. In PKIX, you need the CA's root certificate. When pinning, you need to know the host's public key.

If you don't have the *a priori* knowledge of the host's public key, then you can move to a [Trust On First Use](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+trust+on+first+use+scheme) scheme. It similar to the way tools like [CertPatrol](https://www.google.com/search?q=certpatrol) work.

Pinning works well for enterprise applications. In the enterprise, the orgranization issues its own certifcates, so it knows what the public keys are before hand. They may even run their own private PKI. Since the organization knows the information *a priori*, apps are built with the necessary certifcates bundled in. There's no need to trust on the first use.

One important note... [RFC 7469, Public Key Pinning Extension for HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7469), has critical defects. The most damaging are (1) the overrides, where an attacker can break a known good pinset; and (2) when a pinset is broken, the error reporting is disabled. The RFC did not do a good job at listing security considerations.

Also see Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epgut001/pubs/book.pdf). He discusses all of this stuff.

---

> If have tried 'requests' and also 'httplib' package...

Unfortunately, I have no idea which library you need to do these things. There may be no libraries available.

Comment: I cannot accept your answer as THE answer as of now mostly because there are many things you have mentioned on which I have very little knowledge, so it will take some time before I can try out your suggestions. But I am definitely up-voting your answer for all the valuable pointers. Thank you :)

Comment: @akash12300 - Don't worry about it. You're into deep security engineering problems. Read Gutmann's book. And don't accept answers too quickly. Allow folks time to answer. You might find a better one comes along.